# How to catch fatal errors inside an PHP EvTimer

Tags: php, error-handling

How would one catch an fatal error inside an a PHP EvTimer?

```
<?php
$timer = new EvTimer(1, 5, function () 
    {
    try
        {
        print("ev1\n");
        xx();
        print("ev1 - after\n");
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
        print_r($e);
        die();
        }
    print("done\n");
    });

print ("running\n");
Ev::run();
print ("done\n");
```

Th code above just hangs with the following output, and no indication an error happened:

```
$ php test.php  
running
ev1
```

Comment: if you are trying to catch a fatal error, use `catch (Error $e)` indstead of `catch (Exception $e)`

Comment: That works, many thanks!